# Why default timezone time not shown in timepicker - cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, timezone, timepicker

I am using a cakephp application.I want to get current time of Eastern timezone (EST) in my timepicker- now(). How would I achieve that.

I have set the default timezone in config/bootstrap.php as:

```
date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
Configure::write('TimeZone', 'US/Eastern');
```

Time-picker used : jQuery Timepicker Addon
                   By: Trent Richardson [http://trentrichardson.com]
Cakephp Version  : CakePHP 2.2.1

I have tried above code, its showing the **EST time (UTC - 0500)** when i echo the current time in php but when i alert the current time in the script it **alerts the (UTC+05:30)** time.

Please help me to solve this...

Comment: Read this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone

Comment: What timepicker? How are you using it? Please always include the relevant code in your question! Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: `0.2.9` isn't the version that you are using, it's the value of the `@since` tag, which is _not_ the _last line_ in the mentioned files. Also as mentioned please include the relevant code that shows how you are using the picker / passing the value to it.